# Angular router get relative url path

Tags: angular, url, redirect

My angular app is hosted on prod server on this url:

```
myserver/myapp
```

However on localhost its on default

```
localhost:4200
```

The landing page is

```
"/mainpage" //(myserver/myapp/mainpage, or localhost:4200/mainpage)
```

I need to get the current page url (to save it as query parameter and  redirect back after relogin on background), but I need only that one, that is configured in app-routing.module (/mainpage), and not the whole url.
I tried

```
window.location.pathname
```

or

```
router.routerState.snapshot.url
```

but both are returing different values on dev or prod.
on dev its correctly: *mainpage*
but on prod, its: *myapp/mainpage*, and thus the redirection is wrong:

```
myserver/myapp/myapp/mainpage
```

It should be independend from the host server url:

```
/mainpage
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that basepath `myserver/myapp` is part of the server, then why not just remove that part of the string,  something like:

```
let url = router.routerState.snapshot.url

url.replace('myserver/myapp', '')
```

Above is the fastest fix if your server path doesn't change often.

But if you need more dynamic solution, you have to look into setting [APP_BASE_HREF](https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF) or using [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy).

The benefit of using HashLocationStrategy is then `window.location.hash` will return you the path starting from #, i.e. "something.com/myserver/myapp/#/mainpage" will return "#/mainpage"

Comment: There is not really a build in solution in the angular router, that is providing the angular routes without the basehref?

Comment: Angular does give you route with `location.path()` or `router.url`, but if you don't tell angular what is server path vs app component path, it can not differentiate. That's why if you apply APP_BASE_REF, angular will know after that, all of it is component routes. Similarly with hash location strategy, Angular know before hash is server path, and after hash is app routes.

Comment: I was expecting, that the router can differentiate the server path from the whole url minus the own router configuration, where the base url is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is simple, but mine dev environment was in wierd state, therefore the issue was still there, even if the new code seems to be deployed. So I thought, this solution does not works.

For getting only routing url without base url, use:

```
router.routerState.snapshot.url
```

For setting it as query params:

```
router.navigate(['/navigateToAndAppendQueryParams'], { queryParams: { myRedirectUrl: router.routerState.snapshot.url } });
```

Optionally for reading the query params:

```
router.navigate([(router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extractedUrl.queryParams as any).redirectUrl]);
```